# KnockOut observable array printing functions and not reflecting values

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to convert a json object to an observable array in knockout.js. Everything works well, however whenever I get console.log my array, it returns a function instead.

With the following code here...

```
 var jsondata =  ko.mapping.toJSON(data);
 self.A1 = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsondata);
 console.log(A1.org()[0].suborg()[0].orgactivities()[0]);
```

I get this:

[image]

my JSON follows the following format..

[image]

Any way to get console log the correct input for my values? I am putting the ()s in my code but it's still not working. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your data is a JSON string**: you can use the function `ko.mapping.fromJSON` to create a view model.

**If your data is already mapped** to un-map it: you can use `ko.mapping.toJSON`

I am not sure why you are using `ko.mapping.toJSON` first. ?!!
As your data is shown as a serialized JSON, below code will work.

Example :https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/59/

```
 var jsondata ={  
   "org":[  
      {  
         "orgname":"name",
         "suborg":[  
            {  
               "nameofsuborg":"nameofsuborg",
               "orgactivities":"activityName"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
function AppViewModel() {
var self = this;
    self.A1 = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsondata);
    console.log(self.A1.org()[0].orgname())
    console.log(self.A1.org()[0].suborg()[0].nameofsuborg());
    console.log(self.A1.org()[0].suborg()[0].orgactivities());

}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ko.utils.unwrapObservable`.  You can obviously pick whichever level you want to start the unwrapping from.  If you want the bottom level object to be a POJO for purposes other than logging, though, you should do your mapping manually, using the 2nd parameter for `ko.mapping.fromJSON`, which you can read about [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html).

This is only tangentially related to your question, but you should know that there is another mapping plugin that performs better (I noticed that your structure looks like it could be quite large): [knockout.viewmodel](http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/)